# Is there any NOT operator in Regex

Tags: java, regex, string, tags

String  :

```
The car has <ex id=\"3\"/><g id=\"4\">attributes</g><g id=\"5\">, such as weight and color
```

using the Regex : `(<.*?>)`

i was able to get the tags like  `<ex id=\"3\"/>` and  `<g id=\"4\">`

but how can we remove all the string part from the sentence so that the final string would look like `<ex id=\"3\"/><g id=\"4\"></g><g id=\"5\">`

with only the tags.

Q: Remove anything from the sentence but tags (NOT operator for tags).

Comment: Use same regex in `Matcher.find()` and get your new string using `matcher.group(0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code creates a new string with the required tags.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String line = "The car has <ex id=\\\"3\\\"/><g id=\\\"4\\\">attributes</g><g id=\\\"5\\\">, such as weight and color";
    String regex = "(<.*?>)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    StringBuilder compactline = new StringBuilder();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        compactline.append(matcher.group());
    }
    System.out.println("Original Line : " + line);
    System.out.println("Compact Line : " + compactline);
}
```

Output

```
Original Line : The car has <ex id=\"3\"/><g id=\"4\">attributes</g><g id=\"5\">, such as weight and color

Compact Line : <ex id=\"3\"/><g id=\"4\"></g><g id=\"5\">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String  segment ="The car has <ex id=\"3\"/><g id=\"4\">attributes</g><g id=\"5\">, such as weight and color;
String regex="(<.*?>)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(segment);
   while(matcher.find())
      {
        System.out.println("matcher ="+matcher.group());
      }
```

Output :

```
matcher =<ex id=\"3\"/>
matcher =<g id=\"4\">
matcher =</g>
matcher =<g id=\"5\">
matcher =</g>
matcher =<g id=\"6\">
matcher =</g>
matcher =<g id=\"7\">
matcher =</g>
```

On trying the suggestion by @anubhava This code snippet worked and fetched only the tags present in the string .